# How can I set the correct screen resolution?

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, resolution, screen

I originally installed Ubuntu then changed to Lubuntu because I have a 1 ghz CPU and .5 gigs of RAM.

Lubuntu detects my HD monitor to be 16:10, and it cuts of a little bit of the screen (half the scroll bar). I need 16:9 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

GO to Setting >>> Displays >>> set resolution > 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Lubuntu Menu** (bottom left corner of the screen) -> **Preferences** -> **Monitor Settings** -> **Resolution**

Set it to your screen resolution (e.g. 1280x720, **not** 16:9), then click on **Apply**.